# Suppose non-negative Borel measurable functions weren't always well-approximated by simple functions. Wouldn't this compromise the integral def'n?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

If $h$ is a non-negative Borel measurable function, we define

$$  \int h \, d{\mu} = \sup \bigg\{ \int s \, d{\mu} : s \quad \text{simple,} \quad 0 \leq s \leq h  \bigg\} $$

The definition is, as far as I can tell, perfectly well-defined.  It will always return an extended real number, and if $h$ is itself simple, it agrees with the definition of integrals of simple functions.

However, it seems to me that the quality of this definition is particularly bolstered by the fact that non-negative Borel measurable functions can be approximated by simple functions.  That is, if we let $h$ be a non-negative Borel measurable function, then there is a sequence $\{s_n\}$ of simple functions such that $0 \leq s_1 \leq s_2 \leq ... \leq h$, $s_n \to h$ pointwise, and $s_n \to h$ uniformly on any set on which $h$ is bounded.

Now for fun, suppose we live in an alternate bizarro universe, where that approximation theorem did not hold.  To what extent would the the quality of the definition be compromised? My sense is that the quality of the definition would be reduced, but I am not sure how to formalize this.

Comment: For example, if $h$ is a non-measurable function, then approximation by simple functions fails.  So investigate this definition of $\int h\;d\mu$ in case $h$ is not measurable. Can you find nonnegative nonmeasurable examples $h_1$, $h_2$ where $\int (h_1+h_2)\;d\mu \ne \int h_1\;d\mu + \int h_2\;d\mu$?  That is what I call "bizarro".